# mongodb - merge two objects based on condition field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have the following documents resulting from an aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "description": "description for item 1",
    "item_code": "00001"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "description": "description for item 2",
    "item_code": "00002"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "description": "description for item 3",
    "item_code": "00003"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000003"),
    "extrafield": "extra field for item 2",
    "item_code": "00002"
  }
]
```

How can I merge documents with same `item_code` into one, keeping all properties?
Desired result:

```
[
  {
    "description": "description for item 1",
    "item_code": "00001"
  },
  {
    "description": "description for item 2",
    "extrafield": "extra field for item 2",
    "item_code": "00002"
  },
  {
    "description": "description for item 3",
    "item_code": "00003"
  }
]
```

I've tried different `$group` pattern without success :(

[Here's mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q8ZGOI6oZJq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by `item_code`, merge objects using `$mergeObjects` with `$$ROOT`
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item_code",
      root: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fzM0h2CgV0T)

Comment: Thanks @turivishal . I was moving in that direction, but using $push: "$$ROOT" ( instead of $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT") without success.
To be honest, I can't figure out why your solution work and mine not :)

Comment: group by _id means, group have all grouped objects and `$mergeObjects` will merge objects in single object.